# Go send post request?

Tags: post, go

I want to send `POST` request with Go, the request with curl is as follow:

```
curl 'http://192.168.1.50:18088/' -d '{"inputs": [{"desc":"program","ind":"14","p":"program"}]}'
```

I do this with Go like this:

```
jobCateUrl := "http://192.168.1.50:18088/"

data := url.Values{}
queryMap := map[string]string{"p": "program", "ind": "14", "desc": "program"}
q, _ := json.Marshal(queryMap)
data.Add("inputs", string(q))

client := &http.Client{}
r, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", jobCateUrl, strings.NewReader(data.Encode()))
r.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
r.Header.Add("Content-Length", strconv.Itoa(len(data.Encode())))

resp, _ := client.Do(r)
fmt.Println(resp)
```

but I failed, got `500 error`, what wrong with this?

Comment: You ignore every possible error, maybe you should check them.

Comment: @mrd0ll4r what do you mean?

Comment: @mrd0ll4r I think the problem is wrong with my request data

Comment: @mrd0ll4r I test check the error just now, no erors

Comment: If you get a `5xx` code response from the server, the server has encountered an internal error. As I see, the server runs locally, maybe a look at the server (or server logs) could tell you more about the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Request bodies are not the same:

In curl, you send `{"inputs": [{"desc":"program","ind":"14","p":"program"}]}`

In go, you send `inputs=%7B%22desc%22%3A%22program%22%2C%22ind%22%3A%2214%22%2C%22p%22%3A%22program%22%7D` which URLDecodes to `inputs={"desc":"program","ind":"14","p":"program"}`.

So, what you should probably do is something like this:

```
type body struct {
    Inputs []input `json:"input"`
}

type input struct {
    Desc string `json:"desc"`
    Ind  string `json:"ind"`
    P    string `json:"p"`
}
```

Then create a `body`:

```
b := body{
    Inputs: []input{
        {
            Desc: "program",
            Ind:  "14",
            P:    "program"},
        },
}
```

Encode that:

```
q, err := json.Marshal(b)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

You should obviously not panic, this is just for demonstration. Anyways, a `string(q)` will get you `{"input":[{"desc":"program","ind":"14","p":"program"}]}`.

Try it on the [Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/uAKp18oiGq)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the "Content-Length", and instead i think you need to set the "host" attribute.

Comment: and resp, err := http.PostForm("http://example.com/form",
 url.Values{"key": {"Value"}, "id": {"123"}})